# what does "./..." in "go install ./..." mean in go language?

Tags: installation, go

I am a beginner of go.
I tried to compile a go project, but I can not find any doc or article explaning "`/...`".

```
cd ~/src/ephenation-server
go install -v ./...
```

Waiting for your help.

Comment: The closing of this question seems rather hasty. It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 7):

The [go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/) command interprets `example/path/...` as *`example/path/` and all subdirectories*. You might want to read the section, [Description of package lists](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Description_of_package_lists), on how `go` finds your packages..